# Flink - how to pass JVM options to CLI

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to add a JVM options to my job. So I added the following line in the flink-conf.yml : 
`env.java.opts: "-Dspring.config.location=/root/application.properties"`

When I start flink with the command `./start-local.sh`, my JVM options is well loaded in the jobmanager and taskmanager :

JobManager log's :

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -  JVM Options:
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Xms2048m
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Xmx2048m
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dspring.config.location=/root/application.properties
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlog.file=/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/log/flink-root-jobmanager-1-sic-dbg-agrv2.log
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/conf/log4j.properties
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/conf/logback.xml
```

JobManager log's :

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -  JVM Options:
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xms1024M
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Xmx1024M
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dspring.config.location=/root/application.properties
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog.file=/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/log/flink-root-taskmanager-0-sic-dbg-agrv2.log
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/conf/log4j.properties
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/conf/logback.xml
```

But in CLI log's, `-Dspring.config.location=/root/application.properties` does not appear...

```
org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend                           -  JVM Options:
org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend                           -     -Dlog.file=/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/log/flink-root-client-sic-dbg-agrv2.log
org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend                           -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/conf/log4j-cli.properties
org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend                           -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/sicdbgagrv2/flink-1.4.0/conf/logback.xml
```

My job needs to read my JVM option before starting flink operators (MapFunction, FilterFunction, ...)

How can I add my JVM option so that it appears in CLI log's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understand why JVM option does not appears in CLI log's : because I don't run Flink in YARN cluster mode (but in standalone cluster).

So I did it differently : I used an environment variable.

Comment: I am also running Flink in the standalone cluster. Would you mind sharing how did you add the options to the environment variable? thanks